# how to expose a java application as an API?

Tags: java, api, web-applications

I have a Java Web Application. I want to expose the data from this application via an API so that other tools can use this API and get the data.
How do I proceed with this? I am not aware of how to write an API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many frameworks that do that, depending on your requirements:

- [spring-mvc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)
- Jersey, RestEasy (JAX-RS)
- CXF (JAX-WS)

No matter which you choose, the general approach is:

- write a java method
- annotate it with framework-specific annotations that expose it as a web service

Comment: Can you please point me to some doc which will help me write my API using Spring-mvc and its annotations?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: would doing this expose my API as a REST service?

Comment: @user811433 It will expose whatever portions of it you expose. Depending on how easy to want to make it for clients, I'd at least check out Jersey since it can also create client libraries for consuming the service.

Comment: Bozho, creating REST services is possible only with Spring 3.0?

Comment: Dave Newton, cant I install the client libraries separately ?

Answer (score 3):

You have already written the API.  Any public function is a piece of your API that others can invoke directly.  Technically any function you write is a part of your API, but you have not exposed it to other sources.

Answer (score 1):

The acronym "API" means "Application Programming Interface" and usually refers to code which you can call directly (as in: JAR libraries, frameworks, etc).

If you have a web application, you probably mean an "web service". Have a look at [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) how to write a web service which allows other webapps out there to consume your data easily.